# Controlling sound on a button in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, audio

I am new to flash so please excuse the question if its super beginner.

In my flash documents I'm creating several buttons on a page that will trigger sound when the user press a given button.  The attached audio ranges from 1 - 2 min in length, so I want to give the user the option to turn off the sound for a given piece if they so choose.  I've done so by having a button on the page with the following AS3:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer; 
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fn_clickHandler); 
function fn_clickHandler(IN_Event:MouseEvent):void
{         
SoundMixer.stopAll();     
}
```

I want to make sure that a user does not play more than one sound at a time, could someone inform me of how to apply that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I completely understood your question. But if i did it right then here is the answer:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var SChannel : SoundChannel;
var sound : Sound;

// your sound managing buttons
sound_1.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleChangeSound );
sound_2.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleChangeSound );
sound_3.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleChangeSound );

// sound off button
turn_off.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, turnOffSound );

// sound off managining function
function turnOffSound ( e : MouseEvent ) : void
{
    SChannel.stop();
    SChannel = null;
    sound = null;
}

// are sounds in your library Sound_1 (), Sound_2 (), Sound_3 ()
function handleChangeSound ( e : MouseEvent ) : void
{
    // in my situation since the button names were sound_1, .._2, .._3
    // i can extract the sound id from names of the button.
    // if you have some different approach you just need to adopt it.
    var soundID : uint = e.target.name.split ( '_' )[1];

    // ifi sound is playing, stop it
    if ( SChannel )
    {
        turnOffSound(null);
    }

    // create new sound, from ID given
    switch ( soundID )
    {
        case 1 :
            sound = new Sound_1 ();
            break;

        case 2 : 
            sound = new Sound_2 ();
            break;

        case 3 :
            sound = new Sound_3 ();
            break;
    }

    // if sound was in the list start playing it.
    if ( sound )
    {
        SChannel = sound.play();
    }
}
```

And by the way, use `SoundMixer`, only when you are refering to the whole flash page to go silent.